# Reference to the parent tableView of a cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Is there a way to have a reference of the parent tableView from the tableview's cell?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add this method to your custom subclass of UITableViewCell:

```
- (id)parentTableView {
    UIView *v = [self superview];
    UIView *previous = nil;
    while (v && ![v isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]] && v != previous) {
        previous = v;
        v = [v superview];
    }
    return v == previous ? nil : v;
}
```

If you're not subclassing UITableViewCell, just replace `self` in the code above with your reference to a UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing the cell through the `didSelectRowATIndexPath:` you can get it easily as

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// here tableView is the one you want.

}
```